# any way to simplify this with a form of dynamic class instantiation?

Tags: java, class

I have several child classes that extend a parent class, forced to have a uniform constructor.  I have a queue which keeps a list of these classes, which must extend MergeHeuristic.  The code that I currently have looks like the following:

```
    Class<? extends MergeHeuristic> heuristicRequest = _heuristicQueue.pop();
    MergeHeuristic heuristic = null;    

    if(heuristicRequest == AdjacentMACs.class)
        heuristic = new AdjacentMACs(_parent);
    if(heuristicRequest == SimilarInterfaceNames.class)
        heuristic = new SimilarInterfaceNames(_parent);
    if(heuristicRequest == SameMAC.class)
        heuristic = new SameMAC(_parent);
```

Is there any way to simplify that to dynamically instantiate the class, something along the lines of:

```
heuristic = new heuristicRequest.somethingSpecial();
```

That would flatten that block of if statements.

Comment: @jlordo No they won't, `heuristicRequest` is a `Class` object.

Comment: sry, my eyes were faster than my brain :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the class on the queue as a sort of flag to indicate what type of request to instantiate. Another approach that doesn't use reflection is to make this flag behavior explicit by introducing an enum to indicate the request type, with a factory method:

```
public enum HeuristicType {

  AdjacentMACsHeuristic(AdjacentMACs.class) {
    @Override public MergeHeuristic newHeuristic(ParentClass parent) {
      return new AdjacentMACs(parent);
    }
  },
  SimilarInterfaceNamesHeuristic(SimilarInterfaceNames.class) {
    @Override public MergeHeuristic newHeuristic(ParentClass parent) {
      return new SimilarInterfaceNames(parent);
    }
  },
  ... // other types here.
  ;

  private final Class<? extends MergeHeuristic> heuristicClass;
  public Class<? extends MergeHeuristic> getHeuristicClass() {
    return heuristicClass;
  }

  abstract public MergeHeuristic newHeuristic(ParentClass parent);

  private HeuristicType(Class<? extends MergeHeuristic> klass) {
    this.heuristicClass = klass;
  }

}
```

Your client code then becomes:

```
Queue<HeuristicType> _heuristicQueue = ...
HeuristicType heuristicRequest = _heuristicQueue.pop();
MergeHeuristic heuristic = heuristicRequest.newHeuristic(_parent);
```

The main advantages of using an enum as opposed to reflection are:

- You're explicitly stating the requirements for adding a new heuristic type, i.e. that there must be a heuristic class and that you must be able to instantiate it based on a parent.
- You have a single point in the system where you can see all available heuristic types.
- By abstracting the instantiation into a factory method, you allow the possibility of alternate constructor signatures.

Comment: There are a couple problems with your code, but the idea is still good. I had no idea you could declare `abstract` methods in enums, by the way, so thank you for teaching me something new. Change the `,` after your last enum declaration to a `;`, and change the constructor to `private`, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - meant to leave a placeholder for additional enum declarations but forgot.

Answer (score 2):

You could use reflection, but it won't make the code any prettier.

```
try {
    Constructor<? extends MergeHeuristic> heuristicConstructor = 
            heuristicRequest.getConstructor(_parent.getClass());
    heuristic = heuristicConstructor.newInstance(_parent);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // TODO Handle this
}
```

Only do this if you're planning on having a lot of different classes. Don't bother if it's only going to be 3 of them, your code is fine for that.

Comment: _parent is a class - no need to cal getClass() on it.

Comment: The OP doesn't say that `_parent` is a class, looks like a local variable to me, and it's not likely that it's `Class<?> _parent`. You say this in your own answer, "Note that your code did not contain the class type of _parent ...". Using `getClass` is simply another way of doing it, and is a little more generic. I'd have to test if it would work properly for subclasses of parameter types, but if the OP had problems with that particular line, it's not hard to comment on the answer and ask me about it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't enforce a class to have a certain constructor or a static method - both would be very useful in your case.

As all constructors take the same argument there is one other way to simplify your code using dynamic class instantiation:

```
Constructor c = heuristicRequest.getConstructor(ParentClass.class).
heuristic = c.newInstance(_parent);
```

Note that your code did not contain the class type of _parent - in the code sample I named it `ParentClass.class` - you have to adapt that to your code.

Comment: Why not use the parameterized `Constructor`? Your code won't work unless you cast the new instance.

Comment: You are right - your way is more elegant. Anyway I don't understand why this could be a reason for someone to downvote this working solution...

Answer (score 0):

Is `Class.forName(heuristicRequest.getName())` an option?

Then `constructor heuristicRequestClass.getDeclaredConstructor(_parent.getClass());`

Last `heuristic = constructor.newInstance(_parent);`

Comment: True. Skip first line in my answer answer. +1 for your answer above.